# Cognos dynamic prompts and multiple reports

Tags: reporting, cognos, cognos-10

My company makes individual products that go through different phases, have different timelines on those phases, and have different departments involved. For example, one product might have a 3-day start phase with 3 departments, a 2-day prototype phase and 4 depts, etc. Another product might have all, none, or more of these phases. The phases are and timelines are input by the user.

I need to resolve the following:
1). Allow the user to determine how many phases will be used, and generate that number of prompt sets (a prompt set is a phase name, begin date, end date, and product ID [which is the same for each phase]). However many prompt sets are requested, that would correspond to the number of phases output.

I have currently hard-coded 5 prompt sets, but I want it dynamic and user-driven, since they know how many phases they want to query and which dates correspond to those phases.

2). Provide a sum for each phase, then an overall sum.

3). Provide percentages (phase % of total, employee % of phase total) (optional)

Right now, I have a static number of prompts leading to a static number of crosstab report outputs. It looks like this:

```
                         **D E P A R T M E N T S**
                     Design   | Req  |   Rev   |  Total
Phase: Start        hrs|amt    hrs|amt hrs|amt | hrs|amt     
BegDt  Endt  Emp
1/3    1/6   Sue     1 |100    2|200           |   3|300
              JJ               3|300           |   3|300
             Ted                         2|200 |   2|200
                     ___________________________________
Total                1|100     5|500     2|200 |   8|800


                     Build   | Design | Model   |  Rev   |  Total
Phase: Proto        hrs|amt    hrs|amt hrs|amt   hrs|amt | hrs|amt     
BegDt  Endt  Emp
1/7    1/8   Joe     1 |100    1|100                     |   2|200
             Chris                       3|300           |   3|300
             Patty             1|100     2|200    2|200  |   5|500
                     ____________________________________|_________
Total                1|100     2|200     5|500    2|200  |  10|1000
```

I want it to look like:  (notice all phases have all all departments)

```
                                 **D E P A R T M E N T S**
                     Build   | Design | Model   |  Rev   |  Req    |  Total
Phase: Start        hrs|amt    hrs|amt hrs|amt   hrs|amt  hrs|amt  | hrs|amt     
BegDt  Endt  Emp
1/3    1/6   Sue      1|100                                 2|200  |   3|300
              JJ                                            3|300  |   3|300
             Ted                                   2|200           |   2|200
                     ________________________________________________________
Start Subtotal        1|100                        2|200    5|500  |   8|800

                     Build   | Design | Model   |  Rev   |  Req    |  Total
Phase: Proto        hrs|amt    hrs|amt hrs|amt   hrs|amt  hrs|amt  | hrs|amt     
BegDt  Endt  Emp
1/3    1/6   Joe     1|100       1|100                             |   2|200
           Chris                         3|300                     |   3|300
           Patty                 1|100   2|200     2|200           |   5|500
                     ________________________________________________________
Proto Subtotal       1|100       2|200   5|500     2|200           |  10|1000
                     ________________________________________________________
Total:               2|200       2|200   5|500     4|400    5|500  |  18|1800
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I've done similar thing once.
Unfortunately Report Studio can't create prompts (and variables) dynamically.
You can construct your set of prompts using JavaScript. Not Cognos prompts. HTML EditBoxes. Then carefully pass values from EditBoxes to real hidden prompt as text.